Hello, i want to replicate the Möller's diagram in Latex, Does Know to replicate it? Thanks
Want to replicate this graph and don't know packages very well to get started drawing. Please any direction would help.


Welcome to TeX.SX! There are a lot of ways to do this. Please show what you tried to far to make it easier for others to help you. You could use a TikZ matrix or maybe the nicematrix package, but these are only suggestions.

You've already tagged your question with [tag:tikz-pgf]. So it seems you are already knowing one package to start the drawing. So you should show your problem in using that package.

Related: Array of numbers with arrows

This question is similar to: Array of numbers with arrows. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Since the OP appears to be starting from zero, here is an answer as a tutorial.  I'm using Metapost as the drawing language.  Follow the link for tutorials and manuals.  And I have wrapped this up in the luamplib package so you need to use lualatex to compile it.
You can start with the plain table of numbers.  Here is my regular MP template with two nested loops to draw the table:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  for i = 1 upto 4:
    for j = i upto 7:
      label(decimal j, (34i, -21j));
    endfor
  endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

The label macro draws string at the given point.  The decimal function turns a numeric value into a string.  If you compile this with lualatex you should get a PDF file that looks like this:

this is the core of the diagram, the rest is just decoration.
Next you can add the static parts of each label.
beginfig(1);
  string s[];
  s1 = "\mathrm{s}^2";
  s2 = "\mathrm{p}^6";
  s3 = "\mathrm{d}^{10}";
  s4 = "\mathrm{f}^{14}";
  for i = 1 upto 4:
    for j = i upto 7:
      label("$" & decimal j & s[i] & "$", (34i, -21j));
    endfor
  endfor
endfig;

Since the fixed text is the same for each column, you can define
them as an array of <string> variable. And then add the appropriate
one to each label.  The & operator splices together strings.  Notice that the completed string is automatically fed through LaTeX because the template sets \mplibtextextlabel{enable} in the pre-amble.  This is a luamplib feature.
The now output looks like this:

All we need now is to add the lines and arrows.  Since we are going need to refer the position several times the first thing to do is to make it into a variable so that we do not repeat ourselves.  And then we can draw a line at each point.
beginfig(1);
  string s[];
  s1 = "\mathrm{s}^2";
  s2 = "\mathrm{p}^6";
  s3 = "\mathrm{d}^{10}";
  s4 = "\mathrm{f}^{14}";
  for i = 1 upto 4:
    for j = i upto 7:
      pair z; z = (34i, -21j);
      draw (origin -- (24,15)) shifted z;
      label("$" & decimal j & s[i] & "$", z);
    endfor
  endfor
endfig;

and the output is getting close.

except that the labels do not have a solid background by default.  But that is easy to fix. Instead of using label directly, you can use thelabel to save the label as a <picture> variable, then fill in the bounding box and draw the label on top.
beginfig(1);
  string s[];
  s1 = "\mathrm{s}^2";
  s2 = "\mathrm{p}^6";
  s3 = "\mathrm{d}^{10}";
  s4 = "\mathrm{f}^{14}";
  for i = 1 upto 4:
    for j = i upto 7:
      pair z; z = (34i, -21j);
      draw (origin -- (24,15)) shifted z;
      picture t; t = thelabel("$" & decimal j & s[i] & "$", z);
      fill bbox t withcolor background; draw t;
    endfor
  endfor
endfig;

And this effectively hides the unwanted parts of each line:

Finally you can add a little if .. elseif .. fi clause to put
the extra arrows down the left hand side and along the bottom, and use a bit of colour to match the original.
This is the final complete code:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  string s[];
  s1 = "\mathrm{s}^2";
  s2 = "\mathrm{p}^6";
  s3 = "\mathrm{d}^{10}";
  s4 = "\mathrm{f}^{14}";
  for i = 1 upto 4:
    for j = i upto 7:
      pair z; z = (34i, -21j);

      drawoptions(withcolor (0, 0.815, 0.918));
        draw (origin -- (24,15)) shifted z;
        if i = 1:
          drawarrow (origin -- -(21,13)) shifted z;
        elseif j = 7:
          draw (origin -- -(16, 10)) shifted z;
        fi
      drawoptions();

      picture t; t = thelabel("$" & decimal j & s[i] & "$", z);
      fill bbox t withcolor background; draw t;
    endfor
  endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

which you can compile with lualatex to get a PDF like this:


\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=2.5em}]
\path (\fpeval{180+atand(2/3)}:1.2) coordinate (A);
\clip (-1.5,1) -- ++(0,-10) -- ++(7.5,0) -- ++(0,6) -- ++(-1.5,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-1.5,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-1.5,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-1.5,0) -- ++(0,1) -- cycle;
\foreach \x in {1,...,8} \draw[Stealth-, red, thick] (A) ++(0,-\x) -- ++(\fpeval{atand(2/3)}:10);
\foreach \x in {0,...,8} \path (0,-\x) node {\ifnum \x > 0 \(\x\mathrm{s}^2\) \fi};
\foreach \x in {0,...,7} \path (1.5,-\x) node {\ifnum \x > 1 \(\x\mathrm{p}^6\) \fi};
\foreach \x in {0,...,6} \path (3,-\x) node {\ifnum \x > 2 \(\x\mathrm{d}^{10}\) \fi};
\foreach \x in {0,...,5} \path (4.5,-\x) node {\ifnum \x > 3 \(\x\mathrm{f}^{14}\) \fi};
\foreach \x in {0,...,4} \path (6,-\x) node {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


